# How to find the biggest symmetric word using Python in quick way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, symmetric

I have a text like this:

```
a ab aba bob dod doood zoroz rar goog bnb
```

and I want to find the biggest symmetric word in this text. How can I do it?

I'm looking for the fastest way possible.

Comment: If you block on spaces then this is the same problem as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring.

Comment: I imagine the problem is significantly easier with already made potential palindromes  ;P

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't want to hand over the entire code to you, let me break it down :

```
Break the sentence down into a list of words 
Initialise a variable to hold the maximum length of the pallindrome (maxlen = 0)
Initialise a variable to hold the word with this lenght ( result = "" )
For word in list :
    if word is a pallindrome and length(word) > maxlen
        maxlen = length(word)
        result = word
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do it:

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:16:48) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> words = 'a ab aba bob dod doood zoroz rar goog bnb'
>>> max((word for word in words.split() if word == word[::-1]), key=len)
'doood'
>>>
```

Comment: What if my text looks like this?
text="abaroorppooppwooow"
How can I find the biggest one without split function?

Comment: so your problem is totally different than what you posted ....

Comment: @user3194835 I suggest you first google for "longest palindrome in a string"